# what is the advantages of using linq2sql or entity framework over classing ado.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

> Can any one tell me in detail what are the advantages of using linq2sql or entity framework over classic ado.net or using stored procedures with sql server, which is the best for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage always lying in hiding the complexity of opening the connection with manual process and closing it. All these frameworks make your code more standard followed and similar standards for the developer , but all the framework encapsulation comes with some cost like performance. In some of the rare requirement having your own SP will help you to write better code than dependent on the frameworks. In my personal project i was working with LINQtoSQL first but I found it be slow and less controled by myself . Later I moved to native ADO.NET with Stored Procedures, but if your team is having some fresher people it will be good to use the framework because it will take care of most of the important stuffs like closing the connection once the request is over etc... My take if you are good and you know how to do it use the ADO.NET otherwise let the Microsoft developer do for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use simple queries in your application then go for the linq to sql and entity framework but if you need to use complex queries then use ado.net and sql